# Best approach for storing and reading notifications in Redis (Json or multiple data structure)?

Tags: database, json, database-design, data-structures, redis

I want to store in a sorted set or a list of Redis the notifications of my application (is a link shortener that has notifications also). I have different types of notifications so I can't store them like a normal string. For example if I want to store:

- Notification text
- Type of notification

I have two approaches. One is to serialize the Json and store like a plain string and deserialize when I want to use it. Or the other approach is to save the keys in the list and hit again Redis to another data structure to get the notification hash by the key that was stored in the list.

Like a notification system,the system will be reading and writing **all the time**.

So in few lines **deserialization and serialization VS splitted data and multiple DB hits?**

I don't have too much experience with this type of decisions, so maybe someone has faced this and knows what is the best approach in terms of efficiency and scalability, or at least could explain me how to make the decision decision, because like many things, the decision for me/my app is not the decision for others/other ones app.

Thank you :)

Comment: Redis allows you to store a hash. Isn't it the best of two worlds for you?

Comment: That's the problem that I don't know which is the best to go for :), the list of keys + hashes or a list of serialized data.

Comment: Try all of them and see :)

Comment: @sLoK did you implement read/unread state for your notification? If so can you please give an hint for the structure you chose? And how  you changed read state

Comment: @MarcelDjaman Hi! Sorry for the delay, I missed it. Yeah I implemented the read and unread state, this was a long ago, sorry if I don't remember all, but the approach is to maintain different data structures, read, unread, and all (yeah we have duplicates, but what the hell this is NoSQL and redis is cheap in memory xD) I implemented with a zset so is sorted by the score (the score is a unix timestamp). Here you have the source code :) [https://github.com/slok/dwarf/blob/master/dwarf/notifications/models.py]

Comment: thk you for the link and the answer, much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 4):

After doing some tests, **The best scores goes to the Json serialized data case**. I suppose that also depends of the serialization structure. In the test case it only serializes a 2 fields structure.

Some results (Time in seconds):

```
Users: 600
Notifications per user: 1200
--------------------
#### With Json in Set structure ####
Write time: 93.0
Read time: 6.65
dbsize (number of keys): 600
Memory: 150.60M
#### With set and hash data structures ####
Write time: 367.72
Read time: 40.2
dbsize (number of keys): 721200
Memory: 224.17M
```

I will explain a little bit the tests for the measurements (I used Python):

For the Json serialization case I used a sorted set(zset)(a notification zset per user), that its score is the unix timestamp (float). It serializes a 2 field hash (Python dict) and adds the string to the sorted set.

For the retrieval I get all the zset strings and I deserialize one by one the data.

For the Hash approach I used 3 data structures:

- The simplest one is a counter per notification zset, used for the creation of the
  unique key per notification(I tested also with uuids and the result was the same more or less, so not big difference)
- Another data structure is the zsets, the same as the Json case but instead of storing the Json data, we store the  notification hash keys
- And the last one are the notifications hashes that contain all the data fields

and to retrieve the data. More or less the same as the json case, I get all the keys from each zset and then I get one by one all the the notifications.

I know that this case is not the one that I am facing, because normally I wouldn't retrieve all the notifications,and also the test may have bugs or there are better approaches for this situation.

Anyway, here are some [measurements and the test script](https://gist.github.com/slok/5310348)